# Nodemon Not Loading .env Variables in Node.js 20.9.0 (undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, nodemon

There's a built-in .env files support starting from Node.js `v20.6.0` (no need for dotenv)
But when I run my application using `node --env-file=.env index.js`, the environment variables load correctly. However, when I try to run the same application using nodemon with the script `npm run dev`, the environment variables are undefined.

- Node.js Version: 20.9.0
- Nodemon Version: 3.0.1

I tried to configure **package.json** from
`"scripts": {"dev": "nodemon index.js"},` 
to
`"scripts": {"dev": "nodemon --exec 'node --env-file=.env index.js'"}` but it was still undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution 1:

After some troubleshooting, I found that the issue was related to how the quotes were being interpreted. By removing the quotes around the `node --env-file=.env index.js` part of the command, the problem was resolved.

```
"dev": "nodemon --exec node --env-file=.env index.js"
```

**Key Takeaway:**
In certain environments or shell configurations, the way quotes are handled in package.json scripts can lead to unexpected behaviors or errors. If you encounter similar issues, adjusting the use of quotes in your script commands might provide a solution.

## Solution 2

Also i found another solution which is adding `nodemon.json` to the root folder and adding the following to it

```
{
    "execMap": {
      "js": "node --env-file=.env"
    }
}
```

now you can keep the same `"dev": "nodemon index.js"` of `package.json` untouched.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your dev script like this:

```
"dev": "nodemon --env-file=.env index.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

**You wrote**:

```
nodemon --exec 'node --env-file=.env index.js'
```

But, you'll want the `index.js` to be **outside the quotes**:

```
» npx nodemon --exec 'node --env-file=.env' index.js
```

**Demo**:

```
» cat .env
ENVIRONMENT_NAME=local

» cat index.js
console.log(process.env.ENVIRONMENT_NAME);

» npx nodemon --exec 'node --env-file=.env' index.js
[nodemon] 3.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node --env-file=.env index.js`
local
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

The same also works via package script:

```
» cat package.json
{
  "name": "env",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx nodemon --exec 'node --env-file=.env' index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

» npm start

> env@1.0.0 start
> npx nodemon --exec 'node --env-file=.env' index.js

[nodemon] 3.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node --env-file=.env index.js`
local
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Comment: That did not resolve the issue. Both your command and mine work when executed directly in the command line. However, when I configure the command in package.json and run it with npm run dev, it fails to function correctly. Thanks for your answer though.